# Related to Discontinuity Property of Floor Function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, discrete-mathematics, continuity, ceiling-and-floor-functions

For each $x \in \mathbb R$ let $\lfloor x \rfloor := \max\{n ∈ \mathbb Z : n ≤ x\}$ and consider
$f: \mathbb R → \mathbb R$ such that
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
0 & \textrm{when } x=0, \\
x^2\left\lfloor \tfrac1x \right\rfloor & \textrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

Prove that $f$ is discontinuous at all points of the form $x_0 = \tfrac1n$, with $n \in \mathbb Z \setminus \{0\}$.

If possible, can you please help solve it in epsilon-delta criterion? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Assume $ n>1$.

$$\begin{align*}
x\in\left(\frac1n,\frac1{n-1}\right]&\implies n-1\le\frac1x<n\\
&\implies f(x)=x^2(n-1)\\
&\implies\lim_{x\to\frac1n^+}f(x)=\frac{n-1}{n^2}
\end{align*}$$

$$x\in\left(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac 1n\right]\implies $$
$$n\le\frac 1x<n+1 \implies$$
$$f(x)=x^2n\implies$$
$$\lim_{x\to\frac 1n^-}f(x)=\frac 1n$$

...

Comment: Thank you very much good sire. I wonder if we can somehow solve this problem using the epsilon-delta criterion?

Comment: @HungDo I am happy if you are happy even if i will loose points tomorrow.